# Why not define boundary to be $\partial S= S-S^o$?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, intuition

The standard definition of boundary is $\partial S= \bar{S}- S$. Intuitvely in geometric shapes it seems to be the same as  $S-S^o$, is there a reason we use the closure definition instead of the interior? (e.g. an example where it doesn't make sense)

Comment: The reason is so that things like $(0,1)$ have boundary.

Comment: Ultimately it's a choice, but note that the two definitions are related by $S - S^o = (\partial (S^c))^c$.

Comment: The standard definition of boundary is $\partial S = \overline{S}-S^\circ$ BTW.

Answer (score 3):

Because then, for instance, the boundary of an open disk in the plane would be empty. But the idea is that it is the circle corresponding to the disk.

Comment: Some texts call $\overline{S}-S$ the *frontier* of $S$, denoted $\text{Fr}(S)$. This is rare nowadays.